# Context menu taking time to load and no option to show loading details

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am trying out examples of react aggrid and I am struck with a situation below.

I am using context menu ( showing it on left click instead of right click using [this link](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-enterprise/issues/72)) which will be populated based on data from API. Since its an asynchronous call, its taking time to get data and context menu is not showing up till that time.

Can I know if there is an option which displays a context menu with 'loading' item and then refreshes the context menu based on data from API?

[This is the codesandbox link for it](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-butterfly-k6bdw)

A work around that we identified was showing a menu with "Loading details..." as menu item, make a call to API and after API call is successful, hide the menu and again open it with the new data. But I felt this is not a right approach and there could be a better solution for it.

Below is some part of code used:

```
cell.beans.contextMenuFactory.showMenu(rowNode,  column, this.showLoading(), testEvent);
let menuData = await this.getData(testEvent);
params.api.hidePopupMenu();
cell.beans.contextMenuFactory.showMenu(rowNode, column, menuData, testEvent );
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, there is no *right* way to make it, this feature just not yet implemented:

> AG-2613 Context Menu - Allow context menu to be provided asynchronously
>
> [Check pipeline](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline) (put 2613 into search input)

*P.S. I also tried to achieve that in different ways but without success.*